# Evenly spread results set over a number of days PHP

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I am trying to disperse the results of 3 queries in a very specific manner across any number of days. Each result from each array represents 1 phone call, and I want a total of 18 phone calls per day.

I need a total of 18 total results per day broken down by:

```
8 $active_costco results
4 $inactive_costso results
3 $bashas results
3 $afs results

$active_costco returns 321 total results
$inactive_costco returns 119 total results 
$bashas returns 64 total results
$afs returns 47 results
```

**I need the total number of results to be 18 per day, so if there are no more $afs or $inactive_costco's, fill in to 18 with $active_costcos.**

Here is the php I have currently (it only divides the active_costcos across 8 per day)

```
        $active_costco = sql::results($query);

$inactive_costco = sql::results();

$bashas = sql::results("");

$afs = sql::results("");
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$str = 'INSERT pharmacy.dbo.hotlist (employee_id, store_id, follow_up_date, created_at, status, urgency)VALUES';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($active_costco); $i++)
{
    if ($i%8 == 0)
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . '+1 Weekday'));
    }
    $str .= "('0CS',". $active_costco[$i]['id'] . ", '$date', '". date('Y-m-d H:m.s') . "', 1, 3)";
    $str .= ($i == count($active_costco)-1)? '': ',';
    $str .= '<br />';
}
echo $str;
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: almost certainly `WHERE regdate > '07/01/2012'` isn't going to work the way you're thinking, unless that happens to be your DB's native date-as-string format.

Comment: The sql statements are all working (for sql server 2008). They all return the results sets listed above. Its managing the dispersion of the results that I am having trouble figuring out

Comment: When the data sources deplete, what is the desired priority for filling in? Which data group(s) pull from first to fill in to 18?

Comment: @SetSailMedia It should pull additional calls from $active_costco (the largest group) as each source runs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a little time on this, here is the solution I came up with:

```
$str = 'INSERT pharmacy.dbo.hotlist (employee_id, store_id, follow_up_date, created_at, status, urgency)VALUES';
do 
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . " +1 Weekday"));
    $today = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i ++)
    {
        $basha = array_pop($bashas);
        $associated = array_pop($afs);
        if (!empty($basha))
            $today[] = $basha;
        if (!empty($associated))
            $today[] = $associated;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        $inactive = array_pop($inactive_costco);
        if (!empty($inactive))
            $today[] = $inactive;   
    }

    $count = 18 - count($today);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $active = array_pop($active_costco);
        if (!empty($active))
            $today[] = $active;
    }

    $calls_left = count($active_costco) + count($inactive_costco) + count($bashas) + count($afs);
    foreach ($today as $v)
    {
        echo "Store ID = " . $v['id'] . " Date = " . $date . "<br />";
    }
}while ($calls_left > 0);
```

It goes through and pops elements off each of the arrays (the number that was specified). If it the array is empty (there is nothing to pop) it doesn't add anything. Then it counts the number of calls in the today array, subtracts that from 18, and grabs the remaining calls from  $active_costsco.

Thanks to everyone that put in input.